# How to debug .NET Code packed in .NET assembly (running as Seperate Software )

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, reflector, .net-reflector

I have a software ( PULSE Time Data Recorder ). Of course I don't have its code. But I can look into its code via .NET Reflector. I want to debug this code and to see how function calls are working in running application ( PULSE Time Data Recorder ). As soon as I click on to one of the function which is exposed at Software ( Like Connect or it automatically connects the device and pulls the data from it as soon as I run this software) , corresponding code which .NET Reflector displayed ...must be executed somehow...Might be I have to elaborated correctly..Please ask immediately if the scanario is not clear.

I want to build an independent software component in .NET , which will do the same what ( PULSE Time Data Recorder ) does plus extra functionality with new requirements. So, for building up such component I want to analyze the complete code functionality and method calls going inside software.

### Edit

.NET Reflector provides the code by decompiling any assembly itself. Its not me who is going to develop code, my work place already bought license and adjusted terms...I am doing what I am asked to do.

Comment: Don't be a thief. Its one thing to understand what code is doing for educational benefit, it is completely another thing to copy the same for profit. It may be against the terms of the license for you to even inspect the software in the way you are doing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reflector VSPro will do that.

However, since you essentially want to steal their source code to build a similar product, I recommend consulting a lawyer ASAP.

Comment: @Usman I've looked at your Edit and Reflector VSPro allows debugging, not just decompiling. Just attach the debugger to the tool and set breakpoints. Reflector Standard and Reflector VS don't do debugging, only Reflector VSPro does.

Comment: Thanks...right you are...NET Reflector VSPro would be

Answer (score 0):

To debug (step through) a .Net assembly, you need the assembly file and the [.pdb file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx) that was compiled with the assembly.  If you don't have both you can still look through the original code (unless it was [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)) by using any reflector software (as was mentioned in other responses).

If you are ***absolutely sure*** you have legal rights to do so, you can copy the source code as visible in the reflector, recompile it, then step through that assembly.

Comment: Soyy but I don't have its pdb's..Its written and don't have its source code

Comment: what does obfuscation is exactly in this context?

Comment: It's essentially making the source code unreadable to a reflector.  I updated the link in my answer to [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)).